# TinyMCE popup customization, how to change the appearance to meet Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce, wysiwyg

Is there any way to change the appearance of **every popup** in TinyMCE? I mean changing the popup buttons, title and so on? Popup style seems to be the same for every plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the plugin folder.

```
tiny_mce\plugins\PLUGIN_FOLDER
```

There is a HTML file and all CSS and JS (if any) used by the plugin. Editing this you are editing the popup.

Comment: I see. But even a simple plugin (like html source editor plugins/preview) does not define buttons. Buttons are defined elsewhere?

Comment: And... visualchars plugin for example does not have any html/css, it's just javascript.

Comment: The buttons at the top? They are defined in the HTML file. I'm looking at the adlink plugin right now and they are there.

Comment: visualchars doesn't open any popup. > This plugin adds the possibility to see invisible characters like &nbsp; [tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:visualchars](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:visualchars)

Comment: Ok found the button. But css is from the main theme! So, should i create a custom theme?

Comment: It is up to you, I guess. Either edit the default theme or create a new one.